# How can I change Google Maps markers to display certain data?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need Gmaps markers to show certain numbers relevant to the institutions they represent (for example, if they represent pizzerias, they markers show a number of items on the menu). The number is supposed to be shown on the marker itself, not on the info bubble that pops up when one clicks the marker. Is there a way to do so using Gmaps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with "Marker Labels", well documented on this page [Marker Labels | Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels)

adding the attribute "label" in your Marker Object.

For example:

```
// Adds a marker to the map.
  function addMarker(location, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: "3", //Your number or char here
      map: map
    });
  }
```